# set BOOL variable from child class to parent in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have BaseClass which is UIViewController class and child view classes. In BaseClass I have BOOL variable isRegistrationScreenVisible to show or hide the menu button. When I'm segue from Login to Registration screen I want to set isRegistrationScreenVisible = YES; but it's not setting. Here my classes:

BaseView.h

```
@interface BaseView : UIViewController
   @property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL isRegistrationScreenVisible;
@end
```

ChildView.h

```
#import "BaseView.h"
   @interface LoginViewController : BaseView 
@end
```

ChildView.m

```
- (IBAction)showRegistration:(id)sender {
    [super isRegistrationScreenVisible:YES];
    NSLog([super isRegistrationScreenVisible]?@"SET REG SCREEN":@"WE ARE NO");
}
```

Shows in logs that variables is set to YES, but when it's segue to another view variable still is NO

Comment: Is this real code?  You define `BaseViewController` but inherit from `BaseView`...and who knows about the file names.

Comment: wanted to make it simple for question. Edited the question. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: After the edits, try `[super setIsRegistrationScreenVisible:YES];`.

Comment: tried, didn't worked, in next view it's still "NO"

Comment: The code you have is all happening inside one `LoginViewController`.  If the "next view" is a different object, it's reasonable for it to have different values for its properties.  If you're going to test inside the Registration screen object, you need to set the value for that object.

Comment: Login and Registration are inherited from the BaseView

Comment: They are still different objects regardless of their class hierarchy.

Comment: then what is solution to set BaseView property from different child objects?

Comment: You need the variable to exist in some shared area, so you need something to act as a data model.  For small amounts of data like this, `NSUserDefaults` is probably your best option.  (Base classes are for sharing structure rather than for run-time communication.)

Answer (score 0):

In `BaseViewController`, you need to declare the property with the same name as you're using to access it:

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
    @property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL isRegistrationScreenVisible;
@end
```

Comment: edited the question. It's my fault during preparation question for stackoverflow. In the actual code I have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

Since the subclass inherits the property you can use:

```
 self.isRegistrationScreenVisible = YES;
```